# How to use multiple tags in Cucumber options

Tags: java, cucumber

How to use multiple tags in Cucumber options? I'm using Cucumber version 7.14.0.

If I use multiple tags in Cucumber options, it shows some error like:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String

It does not allow the use of '{}' in tags.

Here is my code:

```
package com.app.main;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(`your text`
        glue = {"com.app.stepdef"},
        features = {"Features"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/`your text`HtmlReport.html","json:target/JSONReport.json"},
        dryRun = true,
        monochrome=true,
        tags = {"@smoke, @sanity"}`your text`
        )
public class MyRunner {
}
```

Comment: Please repost your code and make sure to clear out all incorrect occurrences of "your text" from it.

Comment: Have you tried `tags = "@smoke or @sanity"` (or `tags = "@smoke and @sanity"`). Given it's a single value, putting the braces around it doesn't make much sense (though some of the Cucumber documentation does use that in their example, that seems to be a documentation bug, or maybe something that used to work in the past(?)). In any case, [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/1bce9a5bf9b681347eb6abe8b3dea771f8b317f3/cucumber-junit/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/CucumberOptions.java#L90) really is a single `String` value, so using the array syntax (`{ ... }`) is not appropriate.

Comment: I used below syntax
{"@smoke, @sanity"}
and the following also not works
tags = "@smoke and @sanity"

Comment: What does "not work" mean in this context? Using `{"@smoke, @sanity"}` does not compile, `tags = "@smoke and @sanity"` should compile, but will only select tests which are tagged with both tags.

Comment: Hi Mr. @MarkRotteveel.. It works.. Thank You !   :-)

As you said, i have change my code.
tags = "@smoke or @sanity"  
tags = "@smoke and @sanity"